# DDL string syntax for mysql on Mac terminal mode

Tags: mysql, macos, ddl

I wrote a DDL creating schema and users.  The sql is feed to mysql at terminal mode on Mac.  mysql is 5.6, XOS is yosemitee.

The tables, indexes, are created fine.  But,

```
create user hr identified by 'hr';
```

failed with syntax error.   Although the same syntax is ok in mysql mode.

I also tried  `` ` ``, `"` instead of `'`.  But, none of them works.

Any idea ?   ( see log below)

```
drop database if exists classdb

create database classdb character set utf8

set foreign_key_checks=0

drop table if exists departments

create table departments (
  deptId enum('1','2','3','4','5','6') not null,
  deptName enum('OFFICER','HR','MARKETING','ENGINEERIN','IT', 'SALES') not null,
  deptHeadId int(11) not null,
  deptHeadUserId varchar(25) not null,
  deptAA varchar(45) not null,
  parentDeptId enum('1','2','3','4','5','6') not null,
  primary key (deptId)
)engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8

drop table if exists payments

create table payments (
  supplierId int(11) not null,
  date DATE not null,
  amount int(11) not null
) engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8

drop table if exists suppliers

create table suppliers (
  supplierId int(11) not null,
  name varchar(45) not null,
  country varchar(45) not null,
  reliabilityScore int(11) not null,
  primary key (supplierId)
)engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8

drop table if exists employees

create table employees (
  empID int(11) not null,
  name  varchar(45) not null,
  taxId varchar(45) not null,
  country varchar(45) not null,
  hireDate date not null,
  birthDate date not null,
  salary int(11) not null,
  bonus  int (11) not null,
  deptId enum('1','2','3','4','5','6') not null,
  primary key (empID)
)engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8

drop table if exists info

create table info (
  infoId int(11) not null,
  name varchar(45) not null,
  language varchar(45) not null,
  status enum('obsolete','historical','colloquial','current','proposed') not null,
  standard varchar(45) not null,
  placeId int(11) not null,
  supplierId int(11) not null,
  dateSupplied date not null,
  primary key (infoId)
)engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8

drop table if exists places

create table places (
  placeId int(11) not null,
  type varchar(25) default null,
  population int(11) not null,
  latitude decimal(10,2) default null, 
  elevation int(11) not null,
  country varchar(45) not null,
  longitude decimal(10,2) default null,
  addressInfo varchar(45) default null,
  primary key (placeId)
) engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8

create index info_name_index on info(name) using BTREE

create index place_latitude_index on places(latitude) using BTREE

create index place_longitude_index on places(longitude) using BTREE

alter table employees add check (salary > 0)

alter table employees add check (bonus <= salary)

alter table employees 
add foreign key fk_departments(deptId)
      references departments(deptId) 
      on delete restrict
      on update cascade

alter table info
add foreign key fk_suppliers(supplierId)
    references suppliers(supplierId)    
    on delete restrict
    on update cascade

alter table info
add foreign key fk_places(placeId)
    references places(placeId)
    on delete restrict
    on update cascade

alter table payments
add foreign key fk_suppliers1(supplierId)
    references suppliers(supplierId)
    on delete restrict
    on update cascade

create user  officerMk identified by `officerMk`

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 125: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`officerMk`' at line 1
Louises-MBP:30215.(013)SQL louiselee$
```

Comment: It should be single quotes. See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-user.html). Backticks are for escaping database, table, and column names.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the back quote. It should be a straight single quote.

Comment: works.   But, watch out for an other relevant error.    There is a quote like character that can be produced by vi or textEdit can replace the straight single quote and is hard to detect.